# Enum.IsDefined fails to recognise a valid enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to fix a crash in code.

`Enum.IsDefined` returns "false" in this method when it checks `Item49`

```
public static VocabularyEnum Status(Status currentStatus)
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(VocabularyEnum), (VocabularyEnum)currentStatus))
        return (VocabularyEnum)currentStatus;
    else
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("currentStatus");
}
```

Here is the autogenerated vocabulary dictionary `enum`:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("cxsc", "0.57.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="voc.Status",         
                                           Namespace="http://somenamespace/opennamespace")]
public enum VocabularyEnum
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3,
    <...>
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("49")]
    Item49,
} 

if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(VocabularyEnum), (int)currentStatus))
```

And here is the my `enum`:

```
public enum Status : byte
{
    [Description("Description for item1")]
    ReadableNameOne = 1,
    [Description("Description for item2")]
    ReadableNameTwo = 2,
    [Description("Description for item3")]
    ReadableNameThree = 3,
    <...>
    [Description("Description for item49")]
    ReadableNameFourtyNine = 49
}
```

I am very confused why it does that. Does anyone know why it would do that and/or how to fix this issue?

Comment: what does it say? what is error message?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt By "failing" OP obviously means the exception being thrown.

Comment: Can you confirm in the debugger that `(int)currentStatus == 49` and that `(int)VocabularyEnum.Item49 == 49`?

Comment: @BartoszKP "failing" obviously doesn't give any information about error message, and in which line

Comment: @ArsenMkrt In this context the error message is obviously "currentStatus", as written plainly in the method's definition.

Comment: Yes sorry by failing I ment assertion of Enum.IsDefined returns "false" which triggers the exception in "else". I will double check the values in debugger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your values are shifted by 1. The values for `VocabularyEnum` start at 0, not 1. So value of `VocabularyEnum.Item49` is 48, not 49. But the value of `Status.ReadableNameFourtyNine` is 49, since this is what you specified. So `(VocabularyEnum)Status.ReadableNameFourtyNine` is not a valid value for `VocabularyEnum`...

Comment: I have tested that theory just now and strangely even if I explicitly say VocabularyEnum.Item49=49 it would still fail. I will recheck when I do a full project rebuild just to be sure

Comment: Confirmed VocabularyEnum starts with zero. The thing that set me off track was [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]

Answer (score 0):

First the code doesn't work "correctly" in any case.  I.e. If I try with "Status.ReadableNameOne" then I get "Item2", which I am confident is not the "Item1" result you wanted either.  The first issue is that you are casting an enum instance of "Status" as "VocabularyEnum".  The next issue is that XmlEnumAttribute is just an attribute and not an "operable" part of the .Net enum logic.

In order to get a version that works as I would understand is needed will require taking the int value of the currentStatus param and finding a VocabularyItem which has that matching XmlEnumAttribute attribute.

The example below does exactly this approach.  It is ugly to think this is necessary, but it is flawless in my test.  Be wary of performance concerns.

E.g.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(CheckStatus(Status.ReadableNameOne));
        Debug.WriteLine(CheckStatus(Status.ReadableNameFourtyNine));
    }

    public static VocabularyEnum CheckStatus(Status currentStatus)
    {
        var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VocabularyEnum)).Cast<object>().Where(e =>
            ((XmlEnumAttribute)typeof(VocabularyEnum)
                    .GetMember(e.ToString())[0]
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false)[0])
                    .Name == ((int)currentStatus).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
            return (VocabularyEnum)result;
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("currentStatus");
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("cxsc", "0.57.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "voc.Status",
                                               Namespace = "http://somenamespace/opennamespace")]
    public enum VocabularyEnum
    {
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
        Item1,
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
        Item2,
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
        Item3,
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("49")]
        Item49,
    }

    public enum Status : byte
    {
        ReadableNameOne = 1,
        ReadableNameTwo = 2,
        ReadableNameThree = 3,
        ReadableNameFourtyNine = 49
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that as well. I will see if there is a way to regenerate enum to start with one or worst case scenario map my enum to Match Item1=0, Item2=1 pattern